# Preserving the Timestamp details in java

Tags: java, datetime

I've an input string as
2020-01-21T02:16:51.8320Z

I need to parse this string into a java Date object.

I tried using following code.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, flexUtcDtf);
return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Output:
**Wed Jan 22 00:00:00 EST 2020**

Is it possible to get the output as following Date object instead?(i.e. preserving the time details as well)
**Wed Jan 21 02:46:51.8320 EST 2020**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you use the search function to find examples / more information about date-time/timestamp conversions/formatting? I think this can be simple solved by doing some research.

Comment: `LocalDate` only represents date values - no time.  You want to use `LocalDateTime` instead

Comment: One thing, you should use `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalDate` otherwise the time is dropped (first line), and don't use `atStartOfDay` because that also returns time 00:00. The best way to do this is with a `DateTimeFormatter`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, not `LocalDateTime` as that class will drop the vital time zone information.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you want `Wed Jan 21 02:46:51.8320 EST 2020`. The `Z` in the original string means UTC. If EST means North American Eastern Standard Time (other interpretations exist), this is 5 hours behind UTC, so you should probably want `Tue Jan 20 21:16:51 EST 2020`. `Date` doesn’t print its fraction of second from its `toString` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.util.Date
.from(
    Instant.parse(
        "2020-01-21T02:16:51.8320Z"
    )
)
.toString()
```

Beware of data loss. Your input has a **fourth digit of decimal fraction** of a second. That means microseconds. The `Instant` class can handle that. But the legacy `Date` class you asked for cannot, and is limited to milliseconds. So any microseconds will be lopped off, truncated to milliseconds.

The terrible legacy classes such as `java.util.Date` have been given **new methods to facilitate converting** back and forth between the modern *java.time* classes. Here we are using `Date.from( Instant )` to produce a legacy date from the modern `Instant` parsed from your input.

Beware that **`Date` has many flaws** and problems. Among those is the behavior of its `toString` method. That method takes the value of the `Date` which is a moment in UTC, and then **applies the JVM’s current default time zone** while generating the text. This creates the illusion of  that time zone being part of the `Date`.

I suggest you **avoid `Date` entirely**, and use only the *java.time* classes. But my code here answers the Question as asked.

Also, your desired output format is a terrible one. Instead, **use ISO 8601** standard formats for data exchange. For presentation to the user, use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)). Both of these topics have been addressed many times on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

First - congratulations on using the Java 8 time functions - wise choice!

Per your question:

1. This is the way to convert "LocalDate" to "java.util.Date":

   ```
   Date myDate =  Date.from(localDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

   ... or ...

   Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
   ```

Per the documentation:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html
>
> LocalDate is an immutable date-time object that represents a date,
>   often viewed as year-month-day. Other date fields, such as
>   day-of-year, day-of-week and week-of-year, can also be accessed. For
>   example, the value "2nd October 2007" can be stored in a LocalDate.
>
> This class does not store or represent a time or time-zone. Instead,
>   it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays. It cannot
>   represent an instant on the time-line without additional information
>   such as an offset or time-zone.

2. So a better choice might be [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)
3. In either case, "java.util.Date" automatically has "everything you need".  It is a "date/time" object. It stores date and time, irrespective of any time zone.